# Do not discard keys with null values when converting to JSON in PySpark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am creating a column in a DataFrame from several other columns that I want to store as a JSON serialized string. When the serialization to JSON occurs, keys with null values are dropped. Is there a way to keep keys even if the value is null?

Sample program illustrating the issue:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = sc.parallelize([
    (1, 10),
    (2, 20),
    (3, None),
    (4, 40),
]).toDF(['id', 'data'])
df.collect()
#[Row(id=1, data=10),
# Row(id=2, data=20),
# Row(id=3, data=None),
# Row(id=4, data=40)]

df_s = df.select(F.struct('data').alias('struct'))
df_s.collect()
#[Row(struct=Row(data=10)),
# Row(struct=Row(data=20)),
# Row(struct=Row(data=None)),
# Row(struct=Row(data=40))]

df_j = df.select(F.to_json(F.struct('data')).alias('json'))
df_j.collect()
#[Row(json=u'{"data":10}'),
# Row(json=u'{"data":20}'),
# Row(json=u'{}'), <= would like this to be u'{"data":null}'
# Row(json=u'{"data":40}')]
```

Running Spark 2.1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could not find a Spark specific solution so just wrote a udf and used the python json package:

```
import json
from pyspark.sql import types as T

def to_json(data):
    return json.dumps({'data': data})

to_json_udf = F.udf(to_json, T.StringType())

df.select(to_json_udf('data').alias('json')).collect()
# [Row(json=u'{"data": 10}'),
#  Row(json=u'{"data": 20}'),
#  Row(json=u'{"data": null}'),
#  Row(json=u'{"data": 40}')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Also posted on this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73673241/10002593):

> Since Pyspark 3, one can use the `ignoreNullFields` option when
> writing to a JSON file.
>
> ```py
> spark_dataframe.write.json(output_path,ignoreNullFields=False)
> ```
>
> Pyspark docs:
> https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/readwriter.html#DataFrameWriter.json