# write a spark Dataset to json with all keys in the schema, including null columns

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, databricks

I am writing a dataset to json using:

```
ds.coalesce(1).write.format("json").option("nullValue",null).save("project/src/test/resources")
```

For records that have columns with null values, the json document does not write that key at all.

Is there a way to enforce null value keys to the json output?

This is needed since I use this json to read it onto another dataset (in a test case) and cannot enforce a schema if some documents do not have all the keys in the case class (I am reading it by putting the json file under resources folder and transforming to a dataset via RDD[String], as explained here: https://databaseline.bitbucket.io/a-quickie-on-reading-json-resource-files-in-apache-spark/)

Comment: You can replace `null` with empty string and then write to JSON.

Comment: tried it, it doesnt work. and also this would change the value and the data and I am looking to keep the data in tact

Comment: So the thing is , you can again replace those empty strings to `null` when you recreate the dataframe by reading the JSON file. But it'd be easier if all your columns are `String`. Are they?

Comment: not all columns are string, so it would be a problem to do that...one is boolean for example and null is the only value to represent empty

Comment: Not really related to the question, but an empty `Boolean` just misses the whole point of `Boolean`.

Comment: you are correct, but this is missing data. at a later point we handle this and fill in false

Comment: There is a relevant answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44271612/retain-keys-with-null-values-while-writing-json-in-spark

Comment: This question is the same than this one : https://stackoverflow.com/a/66064831/6227500

Answer (score 5):

I agree with @philantrovert.

```
ds.na.fill("")
  .coalesce(1)
  .write
  .format("json")
  .save("project/src/test/resources")
```

Since `DataSets` are immutable you are not altering the data in `ds` and you can process it (complete with null values and all) in any following code. You are simply replacing null values with an empty string in the saved file.

Comment: Thanks for the input. 
I understand what you are saying, however this data will be used for test cases and will be compared with the ds from the project, which does contain null values. I suppose I can put some value there and then replace it with null manually

Answer (score 0):

Since Pyspark 3, one can use the `ignoreNullFields` option when writing to a JSON file.

```py
spark_dataframe.write.json(output_path,ignoreNullFields=False)
```

Pyspark docs: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/readwriter.html#DataFrameWriter.json